# Cypher Query combining results that can be ordered as a whole

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher query that combines two result sets that I would like to then order as a combined result.

An example of what I am trying to do is here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/j2sotz

Which gives the error:

`Cached(nf of type Collection) expected to be of type Map but it is of type Collection - maybe aggregation removed it?`

Is there a way to collect multiple results into a single result that can be paged, ordered, etc?

There are many posts about combining results, but I can't find any that allow them to be treated as a map.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can collect into a single result like this:

```
Start n=node(1)match n-[r]->m 
with m.name? as outf, n 
match n<-[r]-m 
with m.name? as inf, outf 
return collect(outf) + collect(inf) as f
```

Unions are covered here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/125 (not available right now).
I haven't seen anything about specifically sorting a collection.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do that, but I can't order the result (`f` in this case)

Comment: Could you provide the feedback on sorting to that issue, with a link here? It's good input.

Comment: You can sort them in 1.9.M05 with `with m.name? as inf, outf 
order by inf asc, outf desc return collect(outf) + collect(inf) as f`

Comment: Micheal, will that sort them togehter? Or does that sort inf, then outf?